# Strange/troubling behavior when putting phone in car dock

Tags: security, 4.1-jelly-bean, car-dock

I have a Galaxy Nexus (rooted, running stock Jellybean).  When I place it in the car dock, my screen gets flooded with notifications for "shell granted superuser access," and after a few minutes something attempts to send an email, which I know because it raises the "Select an application to continue" dialog box with choices between Gmail and Email; if I allow it to continue, it simply provides me with a bug reporting email message with no pre-filled recipient, a screen shot of my lock screen, and a 4.7MB(!) textfile.

When I check the superuser log, all of the last 200 events are for "shell," all within a second of each other, which tells me that the actual count of superuser accesses is far higher than that.  Consulting the log indicates that the `su` process is being used to run a bunch of different diagnostics (one for `lsof`, one per running process, one per sqlite database, and so on).  So this tells me that it's actually the bug reporting process that is causing the "shell granted superuser access" messages to pop up.  Also, the `su` instance being used is not the third-party root one but `/system/xbin/su` - and this process is terminating with exit code 127.

I have never seen this behavior occur anywhere else - it is only when I dock the phone to the car dock when plugged into my car (plugging it into a USB AC adapter doesn't cause this behavior, which is especially strange).  I have written a small application that uses [UiModeManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/UiModeManager.html) to artificially enter car mode, but doing that does not cause the issue to occur; [aLogcat](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.jtb.alogcat) doesn't show anything interesting while the issue is actually happening.

I am running Apex Launcher instead of the default, but these notifications occur regardless of what's in the foreground (the first time it happened, Maps was running in navigation mode), and whether I have a Car Home-specific shell installed or not.

Comment: If you can't get it to happen with the UiModeManager, you might want to try doing a startActivity with the appropriate intent (if I read the docs right, you might use ACTIVITY_MAIN with CATEGORY_CAR_DOCK). That might trigger differently. (I was looking at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a built-in bug report feature.

http://rootzwiki.com/topic/16019-keeps-asking-me-to-email-bug-report/#entry410481

> This is built into Android. It is a debugging tool that lets you send a bug report. It 
>   sends to you because you manually triggered it.
>
> It is very easy to trigger it, even accidentally. If you press both volume buttons and the power button at the same time, it will vibrate once. Then it takes nearly a full minute before the phone vibrates three times and the bug report pops up. It also doesn't seem to keep processing when the phone is asleep, so if you accidentally do it when say checking the time or something, it will not show up until the next time you unlock your phone. It is easy to trigger and I have done it by accident quite a few times when either checking the time or taking a screenshot (it is pretty easy to press both volume keys accidentally when taking a screenshot).
>
> You can disable the bug report function by going to /system/bin/ and deleting or renaming bugreport and bugmailer.sh, but I am not sure if this will affect the ability to send bug reports for other system apps. Then it won't happen anymore. It can also be disabled in the ROM code by the developer.

Comment: That makes perfect sense! The overly-tight design of the car dock is such that it's very easy to accidentally press the various side buttons in weird combinations, and maybe something about the way I sit in my car when I put it in the dock (vs. at my desk) makes the two-button trigger happen more readily.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting superuser to always prompt, then stick the phone into the dock? That's the first thing I'd try, because then Superuser at least should be asking you questions before allowing anything to happen, which should allow you to get a hint as to what's going on.

Comment: I will try that next, yes. The thing is that 'shell' is not granted blanket permissions to begin with, so I'm not sure how much of a difference that will make.

Comment: I'm hoping that by having superuser prompt for everything, you'll gain more clues.